separate pubsub subscription metrics based on region in GCP metrics console
I was trying to add a panel to the dashboard using mql/promql. My requirement was to identify number of messages published by region in google pubsub.
But I wasn't able to find any suitable metrics for that. The closest one that I could see was message_sizes metric of pubsub topic but again no luck with displaying the message count by region.
Can you please suggest a solution or a work around technique to form complex queries like this that can suit our need even if direct metrics are not available?

Could you please refer to this documentation and see if you find any suitable metric to identify number of messages published by region in google pubsub?

@SushmaJeerahalli No that doc doesn't have the required metrics

Hi @Mr.Techie, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
